# Non-null field is not initialized NP_NONNULL_FIELD_NOT_INITIALIZED_IN_CONSTRUCTOR

Tags: android, kotlin, sonarqube

Sonarqube is alerting this issue like mayor in kotlin NP_NONNULL_FIELD_NOT_INITIALIZED_IN_CONSTRUCTOR the description is The field is marked as non-null, but isn't written to by the constructor. The field might be initialized elsewhere during constructor, or might always be initialized before use.
But that is happening in a values with lateinit, could be a false positive?

```
   @Parcelize
class User(
               @SerializedName(KEY_TITLE_USER) val name: String,
               @SerializedName(KEY_ACTIVE) val isActive: Boolean,
               @SerializedName(KEY_POSTAL_CODE) val postalCode: String?,
               @SerializedName(KEY_CITY) val city: String?,
               @SerializedName(KEY_ADDRESS) val address: String?): Syncable, Parcelable {

    lateinit var specialtiesUser: List<Specialty>
}
```

In this case is specialtiesUser who has the sonaralert